# Using Curl with Cookie able to log into twitter etc but not facebook wordpress etc?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, twitter, web-crawler

I'm using cUrl with cookies and user agents to log into several websites and fetch information. It's very convenient but it doesn't work for some websites. And I'm very curious about why. For example, I can't use it to log in to my Facebook account or a Wordpress site. Surprisingly it works fine with twitter and most other websites. Do some websites have extra security check, and if so , what are they and how can I pass them? Thanks!

Following is the php code I used:

```
$webPage = "https://twitter.com";
$myCookieFile = "myCookies.txt"; //cookies are prepared here
$myUserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US;
rv:1.9.1.2)Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5';

$ch = curl_init ($webPage);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $myCookieFile);//cookieFile used to read
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $myUserAgent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: didn't you have to POST something to login ?

Comment: @Moch.Rasyid I've already saved all needed cookies in "myCookies.txt".

Comment: The same with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR instead of CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE?

Comment: @AndreyVolk I'm not using cookieJar here because I already saved the needed cookie information in myCookies.txt.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this.

One is that a lot of sites DO and SHOULD use SSL for logins. In that case, you'll need the CURL opt:

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Secondly, some sites require you load a page of their site before you can use their submit form.

Third, some sites may use 301 redirects. I have seen some that even use META redirects after login. For this use:

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Finally, I recommend using this for CURL:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading